# Can UDFs be forced to execute in row order (by group) in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I want to apply arbitrary scala window-aware aggregating functions to a Dataset. e.g. multiply the last 3 rows of "column" (silly, but simple example).

Many of these could be converted to native spark functions, but not all (external libraries etc) - and I don't want to have to, since they are used as-is in other applications (and simply want replication in spark).
Each of these functions folds/aggregates the new row and returns a new value (for that row, discarding any rows out of range).

How can I effectively call these arbitrary functions in row order by group? (obviously within a partition - I don't think it can work across partitions).

For example:

```
trait UpdatingFunction {
  /* adds new value, discards oldest value and calculates result */
  def newValue(i: Int): Int
}

class AddValue2RowsPrior extends UpdatingFunction {...}

df.select(col("value"), udf(new AddValue2RowsPrior)(col("value"))).show()
```

Would produce something like

| value | AddValue2RowsPrior |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 //(3+1) |
| 4 | 6 //(4+2) |
| 5 | 8 |

My current ideas are (commentary welcome):

- A dynamic class-based UDF with groups and ordering might just work without anything extra
- Convert `value` column(s) to arrays and process as a (very large) row
- UDAF with a array/dataset output value?
- `RDD.map`
- Use windows and just use the functions as UDAFs that operate on every window, effectively discarding the folding mechanism. (Appealing, since a day of the computer's time is cheaper than my time - but oh, so annoying)

Comment: My first idea is to create a new column (e.g. `.withColumn("prior", lag($"value", 2).over(Window...))`, and call a normal UDF on the columns `value` and `prior`

Comment: @mck Yes, that is a perfectly good solution for this example, but I have many functions that I want to plug in without having to convert and test them all in a new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer at this stage, but where I've got to in the short term:

`mapPartitions(Iterator[T] => Iterator[U])` - rows will be in specified order, and the iterator can be wrapped with a `LazyList` and processed however you like.
You need to detect your own window boundaries in this case.

... at some point in the future, I'll attempt to definitively answer the original question, I promise ;).